# How exactly does spark use batches of data for caching?

Tags: apache-spark

I came across this setting: `spark.sql.inMemoryColumnarStorage.batchSize` here:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-performance-tuning.html

It says:

```
Controls the size of batches for columnar caching. 

Larger batch sizes can improve memory utilization and compression, but risk OOMs when caching data.
```

**How exactly are batches used for caching?**

If `spark.sql.inMemoryColumnarStorage.batchSize` is `1000` does it mean that spark loads 1000 rows of data into memory, and then compresses and keeps them in memory, in that compressed form?

If I cache my dataframe using the `MEMORY_ONLY` option when  `spark.sql.inMemoryColumnarStorage.compressed` is set to `false`, then what it the point of batching the table when the entire table will have to end up in memory anyways?